# How to logout from my winApplication in .NET

Tags: c#, winforms, logout

I use a login from to access the main application. There is a logout option from the main application, which i'm not able to implement, even after googling and trying some things like:

```
Application.Restart();
```

or

```
Application.OpenForms["loginForm"].ShowDialog();
mainForm.Close();
```

Help needed to implement a simple logout option. There's an exception thrown, smth like:

InvalidOperationException: *Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.*

Thnx in advance.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? What do you want the logout to do? What do the two samples above not do that you require?

Comment: how are you storing who is logged in?

Comment: The examples throw the exception. The logout should display the login form and then reload the main form (the way logout works, the most general one)

Comment: i store the user id the as a static field in Program class, but does it matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do is to hide the main window and display the login form. After the new login just check if the main form exists and show it with the new data (for the new user) or just close it and open a new one.

Another solution would be maybe to have a controller method that displays the forms. For example have a loop that displays the login form, then the main form. When the main form is closed the login form will be displayed again.

Comment: something like a while loop in the main method?

Comment: and where\when should the main form be closed?

Comment: Yes, something like that and the main form will be closed when the user logs out

Answer (score 0):

Regarding When the form should be closed is upon opening the Login form, after selecting Logout. When the User signs in, it should send the username and pass to the main form, where it can be verified, and then load the specific data pertaining to that user...